# Magento: get all reviews on one page via .phtml

Tags: magento, review, php

i don't find answer to my specific question:

i need get all reviews via `.phtml`

this code work perfect:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/customer_list')->setTemplate('review/customer/list.phtml')->toHtml();
```

but if customer is logged in, code shows all his reviews...if customer is logout - it's shows There no reviews (all ok)

i need shows review for all products has review.

help

Answer (score 1):

There are some free extension available to show review on CMS page. like:http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-reviews-3122.html

OR

If you want to add review on some specific page then you can for custom code.

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
      ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
      ->setDateOrder()
      ->addRateVotes()
      ->load();
```

Hope will help!

Comment: I made also as you advised: $_reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes();
foreach($_reviews as $review){
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getData('entity_pk_value'));
// mage::log($review);
} How i can apply to existing template this? app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review, i don't think that it impossible.

Comment: are are asking something or saying? I am not able to get your point?

Comment: how i can show all review on existing magento template for NOT logged in users? i told before, for logged in users all works perfect. maybe i not clearly expressed, please try my example code for logged in and logged out and you understand me.

Comment: After loading review collection on product detail page. I have used `print_r($reviews->getData());` code to print all review in array format and it is working fine for both users. Either logged in or not logged in, it is returning same data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can make use of the Rating Model, it has a getCollection support so it should be easy as this:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')->getCollection();
// Some filtering maybe...
```

There is also a function called `getReviewSummary` which gives you anything you want

Dig depper into that and you will find the answer hopefully